# Changing View's ViewModel on button tap causes: "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute warning"

Tags: swiftui, combine, observableobject, observedobject

I made a simple Playground example trying to figure how connecting View Model to the View works with SwiftUI and Combine.
I believe I've done it by the book (check the code example below) but when I tap on the "Increment" button this print appears in the console:

```
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22736 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 18320 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 17200 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 18320 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 21592 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 21592 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 21768 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 21768 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 18152 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 21768 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 20224 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 18152 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 18152 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 18280 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22568 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22568 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22736 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22568 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22736 ===
 === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 22568 ===
```

After that, I started experimenting with the code and figured that delaying the call to the View Model's increment method fixes this issue. (Uncomment commented lines from the example to test this.)
What bothers me now is that I don't know why this warning happens or why delaying the method call fixes it.

I would be thankful if someone can explain what is going on behind the scene and why this happens.

Environment:

```
macOS Big Sur Version 11.4
Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)
```

Example code:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private (set) var counter: Int = 0
    
    func increment() {
        counter += 1
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
            Text("Counter: \(viewModel.counter)")
                .padding()
            Button("Increment") {
                // uncomment to fix AttributeGraph cycle warning
//                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
                    self.viewModel.increment()
//                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
let view = SomeView(viewModel: viewModel)
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Comment: It does not happen in xcode or  iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Playground, but in an App, I would use:

```
 @StateObject viewModel = ViewModel()
```

not

```
 let viewModel = ViewModel()
```

and if need be in SomeView:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.viewModel.increment()
    }
```